# how do you create a stub/spy for an non-returned/parallel asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, promise, sinon, stub, spy

In this example, barStub.called === false, presumably because the execution flow of fooStub does not wait for barStub to resolve.

I also put `assert(barStub.called)` in a 10 sec setTimeout, and it still was uncalled.

Is there a way to stub a method like bar?

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const assert = require('assert')

const functionHolder2 = {
  bar: function() {
    return Promise.resolve('bar')
  }
}

const functionHolder = {
  foo: function() {
    functionHolder2.bar()

    return Promise.resolve('foo')
  }
}

const fooStub = sinon.stub(functionHolder, 'foo').returns(Promise.resolve({}))
const barStub = sinon.stub(functionHolder2, 'bar').returns(Promise.resolve({}))

functionHolder.foo()

assert(fooStub.called) // this passes
assert(barStub.called) // this fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that a `stub` replaces the functionality of the function you are stubbing.

This means that when you stub `foo` to return a promise, it totally replaces the original `foo` function.

What you need to do is `spy` on `foo`, which will keep its original functionality and flow, while allowing you to find out if its been called and how many times etc.

The actual stubbing of `bar` is correct - its just that the stub will never actually get called.

---

What you want (including waiting for the `foo` call to finish):

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const assert = require('assert')

const functionHolder2 = {
  bar: function() {
    return Promise.resolve('bar')
  }
}

const functionHolder = {
  foo: function() {
    functionHolder2.bar()

    return Promise.resolve('foo')
  }
}

const fooStub = sinon.spy(functionHolder, 'foo')
const barStub = sinon.stub(functionHolder2, 'bar').returns(Promise.resolve({}))

functionHolder.foo().then(() => {
  assert(fooStub.called)
  assert(barStub.called)
});
```

---

Documentation link: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/spies/

Comment: Thank you! This example definitely works. There must be some extraneous issue in my actual code then, because despite spying on `functionHolder.foo` and stubbing `functionHolder2.bar`, the `callCount` on `barStub` remains `0`. If I call `functionHolder2.bar` directly from the test, the `callCount` is `1`, so I believe everything is being set up correctly/syntactically.